# Drag and drop a button using CCControlbutton

Tags: c++, xcode, drag-and-drop, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x and I am developing a game in x-code using cocos2d-x2.0.4. In my game I created a button using CCcontrolbutton. Now I want to drag my button to one place to another. I tried with all the CCControlEvents but it doesn't work. Now I want to know, is it possible to drag and drop a button using CCControlbutton. I pasted my code which I have used to create the button.

```
    button1 = CCControlButton::create(CCScale9Sprite::create("7.png"));

    button1->setAdjustBackgroundImage(false);

        button1->setPosition( ccp(winwsize/6, winhsize/7) );


    button1->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(plus::add),CCControlEventTouchDragOutside);
    button1->addTargetWithActionForControlEvents(this, cccontrol_selector(plus::add),CCControlEventTouchDragInside);
    this->addChild(button1, 4);
```

In add() I have given the code to enter next scene. But now it is entering while clicking the button. But i want while drag it to one position to another. If it is possible to drag a button using CCControlbutton then please give me some sample codes. Thanks.

Comment: I guess `ans1 = CCControlButton::create()` is supposed to be `button1 = CCControlButton::create` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events `CCControlEventTouchDragInside` and `CCControlEventTouchDragOutside` are happening when the user's touch (his fingertip) is entering or leaving your button while already or still touching the touchscreen (or while the mouse button is still pressed while the mouse pointer moves).

You would need to observe the dragging process yourself. Starting with a click on your button, change the button's position while the user is dragging (to visualize the dragging process), and then call plus::add() when the dragging ends in your target area.